# CLion - command line program arguments

Tags: cmake, clion

Can anyone tell me what wrong with JetBrains CLion, when I assign to Run/Debug Configurations - Program arguments something like "aaa bbb" and then print it:

```
printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
```

I just got "aaa", when it must be "aaa bbb" because they are in double quotes.

[picture - this is what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHYtv.png)

Edit: tested in other IDEs (Dev C++, Codelite) and it works. Only Clion does not :( Just simple thing and can not figure it out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in CLion. For me, it only happens when I start the application *without debugging it* (Run > Run 'Test'). When I start in debug mode (Run > Debug 'Test'), it works fine and displays the whole string.

I've created [an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-5138) with JetBrains. I'll update this answer as soon as I hear back from them.

Comment: Confirmed!! It happened to me too! Temporary solution for me is compiling and running it through cmd

Comment: @Eli: Nope, still open.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use Quotation marks("") and also make sure to delete any preceding spaces in Program argument text field in Run/Debug Configurations Windows, check the following screenshot.

image courtesy: [uta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1574642/uta) 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcS3D.png)