# How do I properly pass command line arguments to a C program in CLion?

Tags: c, gcc, clion, jetbrains-ide

I need someone to outline how to pass command line arguments to CLion. What I've found so far hasn't worked for me. Specifically I need to know how to pass multiple arguments to the program from the command line.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33599067/clion-command-line-program-arguments)?

Answer (score 16):

If you click on `Run`-`Edit Configurations` you can create an "Application" configuration that allows you to provide the `Program arguments` - either in a single line, or in a separate window one argument per line.

Answer (score 9):

I landed on this SO page as I was using CLion with Rust.

For Rust I was able to add the command line arguments to the end of the `Run\Edit Configurations\Command`.  Notice the required `--`.

[image: clion config for rust]

I got this tip from [Jetbrains](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2019/10/debugging-rust-code-in-clion/).

For C, it was `Run\Edit Configurations\Program Arguments`, as @Zulan said.

Comment: Thank you, took me a while to find this post.

Comment: so, the `program arguments == command line arguments`, because in latest version I can only see that.

Answer (score 0):

It is on the Run Menu, Edit Configurations Option. Provide the various program arguments on the "Program Arguments" input field

[image: Clion Edit Configurations]